# Insert in postgresql join two tables with data types serial

Tags: postgresql

How can I make an insert in postgresql into this two tables if the id_table1(pk) in table1 has data type serial(autoincrement) and id_table2 in table2 data type is also serial(autoincrement)?

```
table1
id_table1(PK) columnA columnB
1             a       a
2             a       b

table2
id_table2(PK) columnC columnD  id_table1(FK)
1             a        b        1
2             a        b        1
3             a        b        2
4             a        a        2
```

Comment: do you have any issues with inserting in table 1 first before inserting into table 2 by taking the value of corresponding PK generated in table 1?

Comment: I am not quiet sure what you want to do? Please add an example of which data you want to insert and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f32f9be005e50e05ddf0f17cc72554ee)

```
WITH insert1 AS (
    INSERT INTO table1 (columnA, columnB) VALUES
    ('x', 'y')
    RETURNING id_table1
)
INSERT INTO table2 (columnC, columnD, id_table1) VALUES
('z', 'a', (SELECT id_table1 FROM insert1));
```

Using the `WITH` clause allows you to do one `INSERT` with `RETURNING` the new `id_table1`. This can be used after its execution in a second statement.